Using a cubic to predict a minimum between two points and their derivatives.
Background
After fitting a parabola through a few samples (value + derivative), our algorithm - in search of a minimum - normally would jump to the vertex of that parabola. However, it is possible that the parabola is only a fit locally and not a fit at its vertex. One way to detect this early (without having to add more samples) is when the jump crosses a previous sample that already isn't a good fit. In that case we need to clamp to that sample.
For example in the image below we started the search from the right until points 47 and 48 where sampled.

Those two fit the red parabola, but jumping to the vertex of that parabola all the way back to between samples 10 and 14 makes no sense. In fact, jumping beyond sample 44 makes no sense. However since we are in sample 48, we DO want to jump passed sample 47.
Problem Statement
Given a parabola $P(w) = a + bw + cw^2$ and a sample $(w, L(w), L'(w))$ how can we determine if the sample is fitting $P$ enough that it makes sense to ignore it when clamping on past samples?
Although this sounds rather non-mathematical at first, you have to realize the goal: to find the first local minimum between where we come from (48) and the vertex of the parabola: the reason we want to skip 47 is because it is on the left of the actual minimum that we're looking for at ~ $-56$. This problem looks a lot like a previous one that I had, except in this case the second sample (aka 47 or 44) isn't in the vertex of the parabola ($w_1$ in the previous problem).
Question
Therefore, a better question is probably: under what conditions does a cubic that goes through $(w_0, L(w_0) \text{ and } (w_1, L(w_1))$ with respectively a derivative equal to $L'(w_0) \text{ and } L'(w_1)$ have a minimum between $w_0 \text{ and } w_1$?
EDIT:
I have no idea how to phrase the above simpler.
I do not understand that anyone would anonymously close this question, making it impossible for others to help, instead of adding a comment saying that you don't understand it, and ask for clarification.
The above question means "For which values of $w_0$, $w_1$, $L(w_0)$, $L(w_1)$, $L'(w_0)$ and $L'(w_1)$ will the (only) cubic that fits those values have a minimum between $w_0$ and $w_1$? But, that is what it literally says - so, whoever closed this question, please tell me what is unclear - so I CAN improve it.

Consider the cubic $Q(w) = a + bw + cw^2 + dw^3$.
This cubic is fully defined by what is given:
$$\begin{align}
Q(w_0) &= a + b w_0 + c w_0^2 + d w_0^3 = L(w_0) \tag{1a} \\
Q(w_1) &= a + b w_1 + c w_1^2 + d w_1^3 = L(w_1) \tag{1b} \\
Q'(w_0) &= b + 2c w_0 + 3d w_0^2 = L'(w_0) \tag{1c} \\
Q'(w_1) &= b + 2c w_1 + 3d w_1^2 = L'(w_1) \tag{1d}
\end{align}$$
The derivative of $Q$ is
$$Q'(w) = b + 2c w + 3d w^2 \tag{2}$$
We can find the extremes of $Q$ by setting (2) equal to zero:
$$b + 2c w + 3d w^2 = 0 \tag{3}$$
which has the following two roots:
$$w_{\pm} = \frac{-c \pm \sqrt{c^2 - 3bd}}{3d} \tag{4}$$
Hence an extreme only exists if
$$c^2 - 3bd > 0 \tag{5}$$
The second derivative of $Q$ is
$$Q''(w) = 2c + 6d w \tag{6}$$
and thus
$$\begin{align}
Q''(w_{-}) = 2c + 6d \frac{-c - \sqrt{c^2 - 3bd}}{3d} = -2 \sqrt{c^2 - 3bd} < 0 \\
Q''(w_{+}) = 2c + 6d \frac{-c + \sqrt{c^2 - 3bd}}{3d} = +2 \sqrt{c^2 - 3bd} > 0
\end{align} \tag{7}$$
A cubic therefore has at most one minimum ‐ in $w_{+}$ ‐ if (5) is true.
Subtracting (1b) from (1a) gives
$$(w_0 - w_1) b + (w_0^2 - w_1^2) c + (w_0^3 - w_1^3) d = L(w_0) - L(w_1) \tag{8}$$
Subtracting (1d) from (1c) gives
$$2(w_0 - w_1) c + 3(w_0^2 - w_1^2) d = L'(w_0) - L'(w_1) \tag{9}$$
or
$$c = \frac{L'(w_0) - L'(w_1)}{2(w_0 - w_1)} - \frac{3}{2}(w_0 + w_1) d \tag{10}$$
If we multiply (1d) with $w_0$ and subtract from that $w_1$ times (1c), we get
$$(w_0 - w_1)b + 3(w_0 w_1^2 - w_0^2 w_1)d = w_0 L'(w_1) - w_1 L'(w_0) \tag{11}$$
or
$$b = \frac{w_0 L'(w_1) - w_1 L'(w_0)}{w_0 - w_1} + 3 w_0 w_1 d \tag{12}$$
Subtracting (11) from (8) then gives
$$(w_0^2 - w_1^2)c + (w_0^3 + 3 w_0^2 w_1 - 3 w_0 w_1^2 - w_1^3) d = L(w_0) - L(w_1) - w_0 L'(w_1) + w_1 L'(w_0) \tag{13}$$
Multiplying (10) with $(w_0^2 - w_1^2)$ gives
$$(w_0^2 - w_1^2)c = (w_0 + w_1)\frac{L'(w_0) - L'(w_1)}{2} - \frac{3}{2}(w_0 - w_1)(w_0 + w_1)^2 d \tag{14}$$
Combining (13) and (14) we can solve for d:
$$(w_0 + w_1)\frac{L'(w_0) - L'(w_1)}{2} - \frac{(w_0 - w_1)^3 d}{2} = L(w_0) - L(w_1) - w_0 L'(w_1) + w_1 L'(w_0) \tag{15}$$
$$d = \frac{(w_0 - w_1)(L'(w_0) + L'(w_1)) - 2(L(w_0) - L(w_1))}{(w_0 - w_1)^3} \tag{16}$$
EDIT
I stopped there because I thought the rest was trivial. But, let me add it anyway:
Using (16) one can calculate $d$. Then using (10) and (12) one can calculate $c$ and $b$ respectively. Finally one can calculate $w_{+}$ using (4) (using the plus sign). Then, if $min(w_0, w_1) < w_{+} < max(w_0, w_1)$ there is a minimum between $w_0$ and $w_1$.
There doesn't seem to be simpler trick to calculate where the minimum is (which, to be honest, I need too); but there is a faster way to find that there is a minimum in certain cases:
If $w_0 < w_1$, $L'(w_0) < 0$ and $L'(w_1) > 0$ then there will be a minimum in between $w_0$ and $w_1$. Moreover that minimum will be less than the lowest point: $L(w_{+}) < min(L(w_0), L(w_1))$. Likewise, if $w_0 > w_1$, $L'(w_0) > 0$ and $L'(w_1) < 0$.
Less intuitive is that if the signs of the derivatives differ but the above doesn't hold, then there is no minimum in between $w_0$ and $w_1$.
This makes all cases where the signs of the derivatives are opposite trivial. If the signs are equal than there might or might not be a minimum and that minimum might or might not be lower than the lowest point. It would be interesting to see if there is a computationally cheaper way to calculate when that minimum not only exists but also is lower than the lowest of $L(w_0)$ and $L(w_1)$.
